# Martian packet with ARP broadcast traffic

Tags: linux-networking, arp, netstat

Server nodes keep getting ARP broadcast traffic and becoming martian packets due to assymatric routing. I was known that when strict filtering is enabled with net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter = 1, the packet gets discarded without any further processing and **IPReversePathFilter** counter in netstat keeps increased. But, the counter is not increasing even we see lot of martian packets.

Can anone please help why the counter is not increasing? The counter doesn't increase for broadcast traffic?